# How to use one terminal with multiple interactive jobs without stopping them?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, background-process, job-control

I have two shell-scripts, say `client.sh` and `server.sh`, which has to work simultaneously and give some useful output in `watch`-way.
And I am able to use only one terminal. So I should switch between them to see what's happening but without stopping them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).
I can't figure out how to do this.
When I run

```
./server.sh &
```

then type <kbd>Enter</kbd> in terminal (before launching the *client.sh*), but it shows

```
[1]+ Stopped                   ./server.sh
```

It there a handy way to switch between jobs in terminal to see their output(internal state) without stopping them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `screen`:

```
$ screen -S my-job
```

This will start a new `screen` session named "my-job" and connect to it.

```
$ ./server.sh
```

This will start your `server.sh` script on the first (default) terminal attached to the `screen` Session. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.  This will **C**reate a new terminal and switch to it.  Now you can run:

```
$ ./client.sh
```

and observe its output.  To switch back and forth, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> again.

To disconnect from `screen` while still leaving your programs running, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> to **D**etach.  To reconnect and view your output again, use:

```
$ screen -x my-job
```

You can also view both scripts' output at once, while attached by doing the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>s</kbd> to **S**plit your view.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move down to the lower split
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>"</kbd> to open a list of active terminals, and select the 1th terminal (the 0th is connected to the top split by default).

Comment: … or `tmux`, or `:terminal` in NeoVIM …

Comment: Also good options.  As with many things in POSIXland, most cats have many many skins.  (Though I'll point out that `:term` is not exclusive to _Neo_ vim).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the job control from Bash. 
You could read all about it with `man bash` and searching for 'JOB CONTROL' (type `/^JOB CONTROL` within the man page of bash).

Nevertheless, with `command &`the command should still be running in the background. You can verify that with the `jobs` command of the bash. This will list all background jobs, there job number and status.

With `bg n` or `%n &` you can resume a stopped job with job number n (e.g. bg 5 to resume job no. 5).

With `fg n` or `%n` you can get a job from the background back to the foreground.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like screen(1) or tmux(1) to run the equivalent of multiple terminals at the same time. You can even log out ant retake them from elsewhere.

Use tabs in e.g. Gnome Terminal.

Use job control in bash(1) (make sure to read the relevant parts of the info file) to stop/background/foreground jobs.